# Django won't eat quicktime objects

Tags: python, django

Django (1.2.5) won't play *.mov files, however it does take flv and mp4 files.. anything special about quicktime objects?

It says access denied or file not found, file is on the right path other file types work perfectly, the absolute domain does play the movie (its embedded in JW player on the site, who state they support mov format, H264 AAC)

what the...

tested in a local server with plain html.. 100% JW player bug.. too be continued

Comment: Django doesn't play *any* kind of movie files.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing things [the right way](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/), Django doesn't serve movie files, the web server (apache, nginx, cherokee, etc.) serve them. So the problem is probably on the side of your web server's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the static files serving has been correctly configured? From the djangoproject file:

```
`(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/path/to/media'}),`
```